# do the vectors $(0, 0), (1, -1), (2,-2)$ span all of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have checked and these vectors are not linearly independent but i need someone to check my work below

step 1: a(1,-1) + b(2,-2) = 0

step 2: a + 2b = 0  and -a - 2b = 0

i couldn't find a solution for a and b, so i assumed that the vectors are not linearly independent, thus the vectors do not span all $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The span the line $x+y = 1$.

Comment: Are these homework problems? You asked similar problems before and you get very good answers from the community. I thought you would get the drift by now...

Comment: You’ve asked a series of questions over the past few days about *very* basic concepts in Linear Algebra. Have you studied this material before plunging into what looks like a series of introductory exercises? It certainly appears to me from this history that you’re starting from the exercises instead.

Comment: I know these are basic concepts in linear algebra, however this is my first time learning these concepts. And my professor is really slow so i decided to go ahead and learn these concepts on my own

Comment: Well that is a good approach, but I would put that in the heading, because otherwise people might think different. So do you know how to check whether or not two vectors span R2?

Comment: All i know is that if a set of vectors are linearly independent, then they span R2. But im not completely sure how to determine if a set of vectors does NOT span R2. at first i thought that if they are linearly dependent then that is enough to say that they do not span R2, but amd pointed out that it being linearly dependent isn't enough..

Comment: Three vectors in R2 are linear dependent (why?) but vectors $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)$ cannot span R2. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although $a = b = 0$ is a solution, though not the only one, $a = 1, b = \frac{-1}{2}$ as well, so they indeed are linearly **dependent**. Adding zero to the set does nothing, since it's linearly dependent with any other vector. So no, these vectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Edit: as someone else said, they span the line

$$
L = \{(x,-x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

Also, check that there aren't linear combinations of the vectors that, for example, equal $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Linear dependence per se isn’t enough to prevent a set of vectors from spanning a space. There might still a large enough linearly-independent subset to do the trick. In this case, all of the vectors are multiples of $(1,-1)$, so there aren’t. On the other hand, the set $\{(0,0),(1,-1),(2,2)\}$ is also linearly dependent because of the presence of the zero vector, but it neverthess spans $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: If linear dependence isn't enough to determine if a set of vectors does not span a space, then what is? does checking if the vectors are multiples of each other determine if they span or not?

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out